# How to run java application with built-in command line arguments?

Tags: java, macos, command-line-arguments

I am making a Java application that is stored in a .jar file and can be launched by opening the jar file either from the command line or from clicking the icon.

For the Mac version of the app, I would like the menu bars to appear at the top of screen in the Mac style instead of in the window (the Windows style).  I know this can be done with the command line:

`java -jar App.jar -Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true`

But this won't work if the user doesn't know how to do this.  Is there a way to make this command line argument "built in" to the jar file?

Comment: Thanks everyone!  The correct code ended up being:

`
if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X"))
{   
    System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the system property in your code in the main method or some other method which is called at the very beginning of the application:

```
System.setProperty("com.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar", "true")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is necessary to do it with the command line? You could check it in code with System.getProperty("os.name").

Answer (score 0):

Inside my main method, I would make use of the built in os.name parameter and default your command line argument as appropriate if it was not otherwise set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you bundle the .jar into a standard mac .app file.
Then, in Info.plist, you can specify all sorts of runtime items, including "Arguments" and "Properties".  Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html